# Local rsync inclusion/exclusion

Tags: rsync

I can't seem to get the command to backup /etc/php5, /etc/apache2 and /etc/mysql right. I'm using two since I couldn't figure out how to do both in one. The first one works:

```
rsync -vahtl --dry-run --log-file=$LOGFILE --exclude="wp-includes/" --exclude="wp-admin/" --exclude="wp-*.php" /var/www $DROPBOX_FOLDER
```

But when I run the second, I tried a bunch of --include and --exclude directives variation and nothing works:

```
rsync -vahtl --dry-run --log-file=$LOGFILE --include="php5" --exclude="*" /etc $DROPBOX_FOLDER
rsync -vahtl --dry-run --log-file=$LOGFILE --include="*/" --include="php5/" --exclude="*" /etc $DROPBOX_FOLDER
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to run it as a bash script using something like this.Would need to be adjusted to your Linux flavor

```
#!/bin/sh
# rsync backup script
rsync -avz --delete-excluded --exclude-from=backup.lst / /home/USERNAME/Dropbox/backup
```

Then make a file called backup.lst in the directory in which you will run the script from
    # Include
    + /etc/php5
    + /etc/apache2
    + /etc/mysql
    + /var/www

```
# Exclude
- /var/www/wp-admin/*
- /var/www/wp-*.php
- /var/www/wp-includes/*
- /etc/*
- /run/*
- /proc/*
- /sys/*
- /tmp/*
- lost+found/
- /media/*
- /mnt/*
```

Here are some exclude/include examples:

```
# --exclude "*.o"   would exclude all filenames matching *.o
# --exclude "/foo"  would exclude a file in the base directory called foo
# --exclude "foo/"  would exclude any directory called foo.
# --exclude "/foo/*/bar"  would exclude any file called bar two levels below a
                      base directory called foo.
# --exclude "/foo/**/bar" would exclude any file called bar two or more levels below
                      a base directory called foo.
# --include "*/" --include "*.c" --exclude "*"
                      would include all directories
                      and C source files
# --include "foo/" --include "foo/bar.c" --exclude "*"
                would include only foo/bar.c (the foo/ directory must be
                explicitly included or it would be excluded by the "*")
```